# finding first occurrence of a regex character set

Tags: javascript, regex, character

I found many solutions online for regex matching the first occurrence of a string, a certain character, a word, etc, but I have yet to find a solution for matching the first occurrence of a SET of characters (or in my case, NOT matching a set of characters).

e.g. I have a string as below (in javascript):

```
var testString = '~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{POIUYTREWQ":?><asdfghjklm,./;[]\=-0987654321`~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{POIUYTREWQ":?><asdfghjklm,./;[]\=-0987654321`~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{POIUYTREWQ":?><asdfghjklm,./;[]\=-0987654321`'
```

As you can see, there are many, many, many occurrences of weird characters within testString.

I put up a regex match to show me which are the offending characters as below:

```
var regTest = /[^A-Za-z0-9.,?()@\[\]\-\/ ]/g;
var wrongChar = testString.match(regTest);
```

Now, my problem is that even though wrongChar nicely returns an array of the non-matched characters, it gives me every occurrence of the characters, as below:

```
~,!,#,$,%,^,&,*,_,+,|,},{,",:,>,<,;,\,=,`,~,!,#,$,%,^,&,*,_,+,|,},{,",:,>,<,;,\,=,`,~,!,#,$,%,^,&,*,_,+,|,},{,",:,>,<,;,\,=,`
```

Is there way to give me only the FIRST occurrence of every unwanted character in a quick way(such as a change in my regex), or would I have to create 2 arrays to keep testing if a character has already been saved inside wrongChar(the long method)?

Comment: How does it matter to be the FIRST occurence? You do not get indizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get only one occurence, make the regex non-global.

To get each character only once, just remove duplicates from the `wrongChar` result array:

```
var singleChars = wrongChar.sort().reduce(function(res, x) {
    if (x != res[res.length-1])
         res.push(x);
    return res;
}, []);
```

Comment: sorry, but I don't really understand the difference between 'one occurrence' and 'each character only once'. Anyway, making the regex non-global only yields me the first unwanted character it finds, rather than the first time for every character.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I gather from your answer that there is really no shortcut to giving me an array of unwanted characters once?

Comment: Yes, by "only one occurence" I mean "only the first unwanted char it finds". However, I still don't see what you mean by "getting the first time" of every character - you just get *that* it matched *somewhere*.

Comment: like having only one of each character as per your second point in this post. oh never mind. its semantics and complicated stuff.....

Comment: I have to add that this reduce function requires extra code found on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_reduce.htm
if the browser doesn't support javascript 1.8

Comment: Of course you could code it manually as well, you need not to use my snippet with ES5-[Array-`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). There are [many](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1960473/1048572) [ways](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9229645/1048572) to [remove](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2218999/1048572) [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/q/840781/1048572)…